# Почему не удаляются слова между двумя разделителями в строчке с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Почему не удаляются слова между двумя разделителями в строчке с помощью регулярного выражения?

```
import re
str = "Сэр (анг) — английский"
re.sub('(.+)', '', str)
print(str)
```

Comment: Круглые скобки имеют специальное значение в RegEx - это захватывающие группы. Обычные скобки (не захватывающие группы) нужно экранировать обратным слешем.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

как сказал [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu):

```
string = "Сэр (анг) — английский"
print(re.sub(r'\(.+\)', '', string))

>>> Сэр  — английский
```

ну и для красоты лишний пробел можно удалять:

```
string = "Сэр (анг) — английский"
print(re.sub(r'\(.+\)\s', '', string))

>>> Сэр — английский
```

Answer (score 5):

Акцентирую внимание автора вопроса на две другие ошибки, которые исправлены в предложенном ответе, но не озвучены:

1. Не используйте зарезервированные слова Python в качестве названий переменных, у вас это `str`.
2. Результат `re.sub` у вас не присвоен обратно в переменную, даже если бы замена сработала, вы бы её результат не увидели.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте

```py
import re
text = "Сэр (анг) — английский"
text = re.sub(r'\s*\([^()]*\)', '', text)
print(text) # => Сэр — английский
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/TPlC4H/1) и [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/l0d3ZC).

**Подробности**

- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `[^()]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)`
- `\)`  - символ `)`